# What is the command service in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

If I write `service` in PowerShell (version 4 and 5) I get the same result as if I write `get-service`, but service is not an alias and `get-command service` says it's not recognized as a cmdlet.

Comment: It works because the `Get` verb is implied. (I'm looking for a reference on this.)

Comment: This misfeature actually works all the way back to PowerShell 2.0

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - it's not a duplicate of that question, though the information in that question may be relevant to Camilla. I call it a misfeature above because I agree with Bacon Bits and Bill_Stewart, below.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I retracted my close vote pretty quickly, but I didn't notice the comment was still left here after; removed it. `help about_command_precedence` mentioned in the answer on that question (which I was mostly linking for) doesn't actually reference this behaviour at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer from Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148982/3905079) is exactly right, and the resulting comments about it being confusing and difficult to tell are as well.

I wanted to follow up with showing how to use `Trace-Command` to find out what's going on:

```
Trace-Command -Name CommandDiscovery -PSHost -Expression { random }
```

Using `CommandDiscovery` will show everything the PowerShell engine is doing in trying to resolve the command you give it. You can see that pre-pending `Get-` is the last step, and you can see all the steps that came before it.

The last 3 lines of the trace output:

> ```
> DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : The command [random] was not found, trying again with get- prepended
> DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Looking up command: get-random
> DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Cmdlet found: Get-Random  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetRandomCommand
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It's a "helper feature" in PowerShell.  When PowerShell searches the path, it searches for cmdlets, executables, and then it prepends "Get-" to the command you entered and it will try searching for cmdlets again.

I dislike the feature.  It adds ambiguity to a system that already has a fair amount of it.  I recommend against using it intentionally.

Comment: Agreed - I think it adds confusion (it provoked this question, after all).

Comment: Yes, it really confused me. Especially because first I also thought it prepended with Get- , but then when I tried just writing process instead of get-process I got another behaviour (green text) and >>.
But writing e.g scheduledTask also prepends Get, so it seems like a reasonable explanation.

Comment: `process` is a keyword, used for `function { begin {..} process {..} end {..} }` code blocks and `foreach-object` loops, so when you write `process`, it's waiting for a code block.

Comment: I dislike the feature, too.  But if they are going to keep it, they should add a  "helper" to get-command so that "get-command service" would give you the same output as "get-command get-service".  It's not right to tell you, on the one hand that it's not recognized as a cmdlet, and then go ahead and recognize it as a cmdlet.  Either that or make a command alias.